# Trying to show that $r = \frac{1}{C}\left( \frac{1}{1 + e\cos{(\theta + \omega)} } \right)$ is an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I am trying to prove that planets move in ellipses,

I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DurLVHPc1Iw

and read this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1738.pdf .

But both sources end up with this as an equation for the paths that planets follow :
$$
 r = \frac{1}{C}\left( \frac{1}{1 + e\cos{(\theta + \omega)} } \right),
 $$
where $C=G\frac{m_{1}+m_{2}}{h^{2}}$ which is just a constant, as is $\omega$, and $e$ is the eccentricity, so this is an ellipse with the focus at the origin as long as $e<1$ and when I put the equation in graphing software it gives me ellipse.

But I don't understand why it is an ellipse? Can anyone show me how it is an ellipse? Either from the normal polar coordinates of a ellipse centred at the origin and shifting it (I couldn't get the algebra to work out when I added ae to the x coordinate) or just by explaining it conceptionally?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864811/converting-the-ellipse-equation-r-fraca-left1-e2-right1e-cos-left-th/3864942#3864942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define $p=1/C$ (the semi-latus rectum) and set WLOG $\omega=0$. Let's construct then a line (the directrix) perpendicular to the $\theta=0$ axis and lying at a distance $FH=p/e$ from the the origin $F$.

An ellipse can be defined as the locus of points $P$ having a fixed ratio $e$ between their distance $PF$ from the focus and their distance $PN$ from a fixed lined (the directrix).

Let's take then a point $P$ whose distance from the focus is given by your equation:

$$
PF=r={p\over1+e\cos\theta}.
$$

The distance of $P$ from the directrix is given by:

$$
PN=FH-FK={p\over e}-r\cos\theta=
{p\over e}\left(1-{e\cos\theta\over1+e\cos\theta}\right)={r\over e}.
$$

Hence $P$ lies on the ellipse having $F$ as focus and $HN$ as directrix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
\begin{split}
r&= \dfrac{1}{C} \left(\dfrac{1}{1+e \cos(\theta+\omega)}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{C+Ce \cos(\theta+\omega)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{C+Ce \cos(\theta+\omega)} \cdot \dfrac{1/C}{1/C} \\
&= \dfrac{1/C}{1+ e\cos(\theta+\omega)}
\end{split}
$$
Write $P= 1/C$. Then we have
$$
\begin{split}
r= \dfrac{P}{1+e \cos(\theta+\omega)} \\
r+er \cos(\theta+\omega)= P \\
r= P - er \cos(\theta+\omega)
\end{split}
$$
Now let $x= r \cos \theta$. Then noting that in our case, $r^2= x^2+y^2$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
r&= P - er \cos(\theta+\omega) \\
r&= P - ex \\
r^2&= P^2 - 2Pex + e^2 x^2 \\
x^2+y^2&= P^2 - 2Pex + e^2 x^2 \\
x^2 - e^2x^2 +2Pex + y^2&= P^2 \\
(1-e^2)x^2 +2Pex + y^2&= P^2 \\
x^2 + \dfrac{2Pex}{1-e^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{1-e^2}&= \dfrac{P^2}{1-e^2}
\end{split}
$$
Now it is just a routine complete the square in $x$ and we have
$$
\left(x+ \dfrac{Pe}{1-e^2} \right)^2 + \dfrac{y^2}{1-e^2}= \dfrac{P^2}{(1-e^2)^2}
$$
Of course, this is the same as
$$
\dfrac{(x+Pe/(1-e^2))^2}{P^2/(1-e^2)^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{P^2/(1-e^2)} = 1
$$
So that we have an ellipse 'centered' at the point $(-Pe/(1-e^2), 0)$, semimajor axis length $P/(1-e^2)$, semiminor axis $P/\sqrt{1-e^2}$, and with foci at distance
$$
\sqrt{A^2 - B^2}= \sqrt{\dfrac{P^2}{(1-e^2)^2} - \dfrac{P^2}{1-e^2}}= \dfrac{P|e|}{1-e^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but I think you have made a small mistake on the 4th line i.e. E=Ce/C=e ? but I don’t think it changes the answer

Comment: @user1318 Yes, thank you! I will make the correction.